# List posts with embedded videos

Tags: wordpress, list, video, posts

is there a way to list posts which have embedded videos in the content. Newly added posts needs to be automatically added to the list also.
I am using Wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to create a category for the posts with the video and then query that category. Can you do that?

Comment: I could do that but since there is like 9000+ posts in the system it could be a but tricky and time consuming. It is the best approach for new posts but for the current ones not really. I need to check the content for the iframe tag maybe and then list the post if iframe is inside.

Answer (score 0):

For this I feel that

1. You need to create one time function which will execute on some hook and will search through your content for the links related to videos(video site url's).
2. If any post having that link it will assign category to that post.